# How to compare two columns in two different dataframes in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i want to compare "pitid" in one dataframe1 with "pitid" of another dataframe2 and want to extract the rows that are missing in dataframe1.

dataframe1:

```
 | id|marks|name|      pitid|
+---+-----+----+-----------+
|  1|    1|  FR| 1496875194|
|  2|    1|  US| -744211593|
|  5|    2|  DE|-1433680238|
|  4|    1|  DE| -366408878|
|  3|    3|  DE|  526286357|
+---+-----+----+-----------+
```

dataframe2:

```
| id|marks|name|      pitid|
+---+-----+----+-----------+
|  1|    1|  FR| 1496875194|
|  7|    9|  HY| -816101137|
|  6|    5|  FE| 1044793796|
|  2|    1|  US| -744211593|
|  5|    2|  DE|-1433680238|
|  4|    1|  DE| -366408878|
|  3|    3|  DE|  526286357|
+---+-----+----+-----------+
```

expected output:

```
|  7|    9|  HY| -816101137|
|  6|    5|  FE| 1044793796|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `joins`

`val diff = df2.join(df1,df2.col("pitid")!=df1.col("pitid"),"left")`

If values of all columns will be same in both dataframe then you can use `except`

`df2.subtract(df1)`

Both will gives records in dataframe2 but not in dataframe1

Comment: used "val diff = df2.join(df1,df2.col("pitid")!=df1.col("pitid"))". this is not giving desired output, "df2.except(df1)" except method is not found

Comment: except equivalent is `subtract` in pyspark... edited answer

Comment: its working good. But its taking lot of time during processing. i need to compare only pitid column not all the columns in a row. can you help me on this

Comment: try the join option... with left join

Comment: i have tried left join but not getting the desired output. each row is repeated 4 to 5 times as output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161682/discussion-between-undefined-variable-and-ashsr).

Comment: it doesn't produce expected output.